# Why doesn't formatting work in excerpt section of tag info

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, tag-excerpt

I was going through some of the *tag info* and was editing few where I find some grammatical error, or places where I can add some valuable information. In doing so, I realized that normal formatting, like using **[ ` ]** for code and  double asterisk for making the text bold does not work in the excerpt section.

I was wondering why is that so. May be its because the excerpt section is shown when someone hovers above the tag, and that cannot support the formatting. But I want to know for sure. As formatting makes the definition easier to read and understand.

Comment: It is disallowed by design with reasons explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62218/158100).

Comment: @rene, ook, i got the point. Then all the formatting should be stripped before the text is saved. For example, it looks very dirt when their is as asterisk around a word because someone intended it to be *italic*.

Comment: I'm not sure about that but maybe we found our first legit use of the `<blink>` html tag: `<blink>Don't use markdown in excerpts</blink>`

Comment: @rene, `<blink>` tag?

Comment: Yes, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blink) but it is deprecated for obvious reasons.

Comment: @rene, oook i see.. :)

Comment: @rene, should i update the question and add the *..why all formatting is not stripped..* part?

Comment: You could but that would make it a feature request, right? I personally think it isn't worth the effort to get it fixed.

Comment: @rene, It looks bad when one goes to read the info. :(

Comment: I think we could have some sort of warning in the text on that edit page that markdown is not available.

Comment: @rene, Ya, that can work.. But stripping all markdown isn't that expensive(computationally) and complicated.

Comment: It is if they are using a regex ...

Comment: @rene, an excerpt cannot be more then 460 characters. Anyways.. I think I'll ask another question with the feature request.