# Formatting in excerpt. Strip all of it or make it work

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-wiki, tag-excerpt, formatting

Few days back I was editing tag wikis when I realized that formatting doesn't work in the excerpt section. I came across some tag wikis in which the formatting was showing (like asterisk and all to make it bold or italic) and it was looking dirty.

I had asked a question as to why formatting doesn't work for excerpt section of tag wiki [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310047/1795279). I also got redirected to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62218/272025) answer which gives the reason as why formatting is not allowed. It also mentions that *"...we attempt to strip all formatting for the excerpt...*. But that is clearly not happening as we can see in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linux/info), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/data/info), and may be other cases which I did not come across.

I think it would be better if either one of the things would be done.

1. Strip off all the formatting, and remove whatever symbols (like asterisk and [tag:]) that occur.
2. Or make them work.

Because seriously it looks dirty and not at all neat.

Comment: Maybe this is more a bug than a feature request since markdown should be stripped. Or is the feature request "make it work"?

Comment: @Tunaki, May be. Hope someone steps up and provides information if really this is a bug or this feature is missing.

Comment: The problem is that in plain-text, using what looks like markdown can make perfect sense. So just stripping it would not work.

Comment: @Deduplicator, Oh ya.. Thats a tricky one.